# Recursive DFS with path not functioning as expected

Tags: java

I have a State class, and it contains an ArrayList of edges. I am trying to compute the path from one state to another using DFS.

```
public class State{
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<State> edges;

    public ArrayList<State> depth-first-search(State start, State goal, ArrayList<State> path){
        if (start.equals(goal)) {
            path.add(start);
            return path;
        }
        else
        {
            start.setFound(true);
            for (State state: start.getEdges())
            {
                if (!state.found)
                {
                   //we haven't looked at this state, let's look at it
                   path.add(state);
                   path = depth-first-search(state, goal, path);
                }
            }
            return path;
        }
```

There is an issue with getting the path of states but I'm not sure what exactly. It just continues looking at states even after we've found our goal.

Comment: What does you DFS function look like?

Comment: Sorry, typo. The DFS function is the depth-first-search. @OskarHýbl

Comment: Do you mark nodes as visited?

Comment: @csharpfolk   States are marked as visited with this line: 
start.setFound(true);

Comment: Looks like problem with `for`, even if your find your goal and return you still iterating non visited edges. It will be hard to return from multiple levels of recursion, but you may use something like `if((path = DFS()) != null) return true;` and `return false` to continue search

Comment: This `for (State state: state.getEdges())` should be `for (State state: start.getEdges())`, right? (Probably another typo, but anyway ;))

Comment: `path` is passed by reference, so you may use wrapper function that will create empty list and pass it to DFS

Comment: your code looks incomplete. Also, you either need `if/else` with a single return afterward, or if you're returning in the `if ` case, you don't need "else" syntax, just run the code because you'll have exited the function already if the `if` condition applied.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<State> dfs(State start, State goal) {
    List<State> list = new ArrayList<State>();
    if (dfsImpl(start, goal, list)) 
        return list;
    else
       return null;
}

private boolean dfsImpl(State start, State goal, ArrayList<State> path)    {
        if (start.equals(goal)){
            path.add(start);
            return true;
        }
        else{
            start.setFound(true);
            for (State state: state.getEdges()){
                if (!state.found){
                   //we haven't looked at this state, let's look at it
                   path.add(state);
                   if (DFS(state, goal, path)) 
                        return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```